# jquery : call function for dynamic created elements

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to call this after page load:
    `$('#chatscroller').tinyscrollbar()`
Here the `#chatscroller` is the dynamically appended div block.

HTML ( Existing code block ):

```
<div id="onlinechatlist">
    <div class="chatimage">
    </div>
    <div id="chatscroller">
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
function tinyscrollbar( ) {
    // some codes for scrolling the particular division
}

function appendcode ( ) {
    $("#onlinechatlist").append(append above html code);
    // code will appended at the last of the page
});
```

The problem is that when the code is appended to the end of the page,
the function ( here : `tinyscrollbar()` )  bound with appended code's class is not executed.

Comment: may you please provide a non/quasi/functional code sample/example?

Comment: Please add that code to your question rather than in a comment.

Comment: i have updated the quest please read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I really do understand your question right, but maybe this helps?

This waits for the page to load, then appends the html, then calls the tinyscrollbar function.

```
var chatscrollerhtml = '<div id="chatscroller">blabla</div>';

function tinyscrollbar() {
  //....
}

$(document).ready( function() {
  $(body).append(chatscrollerhtml);
  $('#chatscroller').tinyscrollbar();
});
```